# Accessing WebToolkit WApplication class from main

Tags: c++, wt

I try to do a little Web-Development with C++ and WebToolkit. My problem so far is that I have no idea how to access my class WebApp from the main function to populate data.

I have a few sensors for oxygen, light etc. In the WebApp-Class I defined some `std::vector<  OxygenSensor*  > OSList` which I would like to access from within the main function. How can this be done?

```
#include <Wt/WApplication.h>

#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include "View/WebApp.h"

//Make some default config during development
std::vector<std::string> make_webapp_config();

std::unique_ptr<Wt::WApplication> createApplication(const Wt::WEnvironment& env)
{
  return std::make_unique<WebApp>(env);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    auto *wa = &createApplication;
    return Wt::WRun(argv[0], make_webapp_config(), wa);
}

std::vector<std::string> make_webapp_config() {
  std::vector<std::string> conf;
  conf.push_back("--docroot");
  conf.push_back(".");
  conf.push_back("--http-address");
  conf.push_back("0.0.0.0");
  conf.push_back("--http-port");
  conf.push_back("9090");
  return conf;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`WebApp` (i.e. a `Wt::WApplication` object) is only constructed when a session is started. Every browser session has its own `Wt::WApplication` object. So, it is not possible to access this object from the main function (as no session is constructed yet as the web server is not yet listening for incoming connections).

Two possibilities exist:

- Initialise the `OSList` from within the constructor of `WebApp` (or inside the `WebApp::initialise` function), which is automatically called by Wt when the session is created.
- Store the `OSList` as a global (static) list, but pay attention to possible data races in that case.